# How to detect if any of the elements in the child component are touched in the Parent component

Tags: angular

I have got a parent component and it has 3 child components inside it. Inside the Parent component I have a save button.

My requirement is that if any of the elements or variables in any of the child components are touched then only I want the 'save' button in the parent component to be enabled.

```html
<div>
   <h3>Parent Component</h3>
   <child-component1>
   </child-component1>
   <child-component1>
   </child-component1>
   <child-component1>
   </child-component1>
   <button type="submit" [disabled]="!isSaveButtonDisabled">
   Save
   </button>
</div>
```

Inside the parent component ts file.

```js
public ischildComponentOneFormModified: boolean = false;
public ischildComponentTwoFormModified: boolean = false;
public ischildComponentThreeFormModified: boolean = false;

get isSaveButtonDisabled(): boolean {
  if (
    this.ischildComponentOneFormModified ||
    this.ischildComponentTwoFormModified ||
    this.ischildComponentThreeFormModified
  ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any inputs or suggestions on how do i achieve this ?

Comment: Hello, if I might, let me warn you *not* to use the getter to bind element in the template. Because getters are function, angular is not able to know when the value have changed and will run it at each change detection (which can lead to performance issues). You can use a value instead ;)

Comment: will keep that in mind, thank you.. it helps me in learning the best practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may want to use is an [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter) in your child component. When something changes (or component is "touched") then you emit from the child component and listen in your parent.

**CHILD HTML**

You have to configure how the `touchDetected()` method gets fired from your child component. There are several ways to accomplish this. Here is one example.

```
<div class="content-wrapper" (click)="touchDetected()">
   <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</div>
```

**CHILD CLASS**

```
class ChildComponent {

   @Output() onChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

   touchDetected() {
     this.onChange.emit(true);
   }

}
```

**PARENT HTML**

```
<child-component (onChange)="listenForChildChange($event)" ></child-component>
```

**PARENT CLASS**

```
class ParentComponent {

   listenForChildChange(event:any) {
      this.ischildComponentFormModified = event;
   }
 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but it was not working as expected, then i put a console log message in the touchDetected() method and made changes to field in the child component and noticed that touchDetected() was not getting hit.... Don't i need to call touchDetected() from some where ?

Comment: Yes. Use an element within your child component. You have to determine where/how you want that method to fire from within the child component.